# Calling free in a procedure in C

Tags: c, free

In this procedure, I am trying to copy 'b' characters of a string 'c' into an array of strings. So I created a local variable 'ans'.
If I call free like I do, my program doesn't output anything (because I free'd it) and valgrind gives me a bunch of errors. If I don't call free, I only get 1 error of memory leak. How do I free 'ans'?

```
void foo(void**av, void*bv, void*cv) {
    char** a = (char**) av;
    intptr_t b = (intptr_t) bv;
    char* c = (char*) c;

    char* ans = malloc(b*sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;
    while(c[i]!=0 && i<b)
        ans[i] = c[i++];
    ans[i] = 0;
    *a = ans;
    free (ans);
}
```

Comment: you can free `ans` from the caller function of `foo()`...

Comment: actually you ape planning to use the allocated memory, so why you free it?  just delete `free (ans);` line

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding what `free (ans);` does. It doesn't free `ans` itself -- it still has the same value it always had. It frees the block you allocated when you called `malloc`. Since the caller still needs to access that block (that's why you did `*a = ans;` -- to let the caller access the memory you allocated), you can't free it except in the caller, after they're done with it.